# JQuery Animate - How to stop hover-on function as soon as hovered-off (dont complete hover-on function)

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I have a menu navigation area where I use .animate to slide the text over when its hovered on, then slide it back when hovered off. I would like to be able to immediately stop the slide animation once the mouse is hovered off the tab. How can I do that?

```
$('a.menu').hover(
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current'))
            $(this).animate({'padding-right': '+=10'});
    },
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current'))
            $(this).animate({'padding-right': '-=10'});
    }       
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method

```
$('a.menu').hover(
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current'))
            $(this).stop().animate({'padding-right': '+=10'});
    },
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('current'))
            $(this).stop().animate({'padding-right': '-=10'});
    }       
);
```

Comment: Ok that sort of works. The only issue is if its hovered off before it reaches the +=10px, then the hover-off function still removes 10px.
(i.e. if the text reaches +6px and I hover off, the hover-off function still moves 10px to the right, instead of just 6)

Comment: hm... are you doing anything else? because `padding:-n` is treated as `padding:0`. (You can't have negative padding in CSS).  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/XFbf5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop an animation, but that won't work well with relative values. You need to change them to absolute values so that you don't stop them halfways and then animate back past the starting value.

Comment: Sweet! That corrected my 2nd issue after using .stop(). Thanks!